# Malformed UTF-8 characters, possibly incorrectly encoded Laravel

Tags: php, json, laravel-8, laravel-models

- Laravel 8

I have seen a few of these questions, but the answers are either msising, not for php, or some weird hack.

I have a table in the database, mariadb, with the field type of LONGTEXT - equates to JSON field.

in my model I do:

```
protected $casts = [
    'event_data'  => 'array',
];

public function setEventDataAttribute($value) {
    $this->attributes['event_data'] = json_encode($value);
}
```

The data going into the field is:

```
array:12 [
  "start" => "2022-08-23T00:00:00+00:00"
  "end" => "2022-08-23T00:00:00+00:00"
  "all_day" => false
  "unassigned" => true
  "draft" => true
  "title" => "ggggg"
  "notes" => "test"
  "active" => true
  "schedule_calendar_id" => null
  "jobcode_id" => 122723308
  "customfields" => array:2 [
    1782352 => "Dirty"
    1782354 => "Vacant"
  ]
  "color" => "#888888"
]
```

When I run `json_encode($value)` where $value is the above array, I get:

```
{
    "start": "2022-08-23T00:00:00+00:00",
    "end": "2022-08-23T00:00:00+00:00",
    "all_day": false,
    "unassigned": true,
    "draft": true,
    "title": "ggggg",
    "notes": "test",
    "active": true,
    "schedule_calendar_id": null,
    "jobcode_id": 122723308,
    "customfields": {
        "1782352": "Dirty",
        "1782354": "Vacant"
    },
    "color": "#888888"
}
```

which according to every validator out there, this is valid JSON. How ever attempting to set this as the attribute into the field throws:

> Malformed UTF-8 characters, possibly incorrectly encoded

I can, above the `$this->attributes['event_data']` do:

```
dump(json_encode($value), json_decode(json_encode($value)));
```

And get the json object listed above and get a `stdClass` class object of the decoded json.

So my question is:

If the online JSON formatters are saying this is valid JSON, php has no issue encoding and decoding it - why can't laravel insert it? Is it the dates? they must be in ISO8601 Format.

What is going on? I have done this, json encoding like this, a thousand times with no issue.

Comment: It's an encoding issue not linked to the validity of the json, check the encoding of the table, it should be something like utf8mb4

Comment: @Lk77 its utf8mb4_bin. Is there some other format it should be in, there's no utf8mb4, the closest is _bin.

Comment: I would try with utf8mb4_unicode_ci or utf8mb4_general_ci just in case if you have it

Comment: @Lk77 I'll try that, but any particular reason whyother JSON fields created using laravel migrations are set to utf8mb4_bin and they have no issue? - curious cat here. it's why I think theres an issue with the json or something